# WordPress LayerSlider not responsive

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, slider

To build the website of our company, [Blue House](http://www.bluehouse-agency.com), we used:

- WordPress
- [Forest](http://codestag.com/themes/forest/) theme by Codestag
- [LayerSlider](http://codecanyon.net/item/layerslider-responsive-wordpress-slider-plugin-/1362246) plugin

Forest theme comes with a native slider but, since we needed to build several landing pages for our website, and Forest theme only lets you build one slider, with no variations, we had to use a third-party plugin, LayerSlider, to achieve this.

We were recommended this solution by Codestag support team itself, as they use LayerSlider on one of their other themes: [Crux](http://codestag.com/themes/crux/).

Here is our problem: although both Forest theme and LayerSlider are supposed to be responsive, our website is not, or at least, not properly.

This is what we get when we resize the window of our explorer:

[image]

Which *could* be acceptable, compared to what we get directly on a smartphone (iPhone):

[image]

We have tried playing around with both CSS and LayerSlider options, but nothing seems to do the trick.

We are comfortable giving up LayerSlider and switching to another solution, for instance hardcoding the page.

Any idea on how to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: why not contact the author of layerslider?

Comment: I contacted the author of LayerSlider, who told me to check with Codestag team whether the theme was responsive or not (which it is) and so did I: guess what, Codestag team told me to check with LayerSlider author. Kind of the chicken and the egg...

Comment: The theme IS responsive but layerslider is not..every ls div is getting a width of 1007px and it's not changing with the change in screen size.. http://i.imgur.com/0eK8fS1.jpg

Comment: Thanks for this. I am playing around with the following options of LayerSlider:
- Full width On/Off: Enable this option to force the slider to become full-width, even if your theme does not support such layout. (On for us)
- Responsive under "value": Turns on responsive mode in a full-width slider under the specified value in pixels. Can only be used with full-width mode. (580 for us)
- Layers container "value": Creates an invisible inner container with the given dimension in pixels to hold and center your layers. (None for us)

Any recommendations on how to tweak these?

Comment: Your best option is trial and error at this point. Enable one option at a time and test the responsiveness. You should also contact the author and stress on support.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am doing. Useless replies from the author so far, though. Thanks.

Comment: This is a question for the slider plugin or theme forums, not StackOverflow as it is too specific to the related technologies

Answer (score 3):

I just had similar issue with LayerSlider (slider not being responsive) on website's home page. The slider had only one slide. I've solved it by duplicating the slide, so I suggest you try that (go to All sliders, click to edit your slide and then on "duplicate slide") and see if it fixes the problem.

Maybe it's some kind of a bug, but for some reason it seems like LayerSlider responsiveness is handled differently for sliders with only one slide as opposed to sliders consisting of two or more.

Comment: This probably saved me a couple of hours. May all the upvotes be with you.